# How to load json data when changing between pages in jqtouch application?

Tags: json, jquery, jqtouch

My application is using JQTouch. The demos show how to GET an html file and display it in the user interface, but I'm loading JSON that I would like to use in a pre-existing DIV. I don't want to create a separate people.html and generate that on the server.

So I have a DIV like this that I would like to load my list of people into the UL.

```
<div id="people">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>People</h1>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
</div>
<ul class="rounded">
    <li class="sep">F</li>
    <li><a href="#person">Flintstone, <em>Fred</em></a></li>
    <li><a href="#person">Flintstone, <em>Pebble</em></a></li>
    <li><a href="#person">Flintstone, <em>Wilma</em></a></li>
    <li class="sep">J</li>
    <li><a href="#person">Jetson, <em>Elroy</em></a></li>
    <li><a href="#person">Jetson, <em>George</em></a></li>
    <li><a href="#person">Jetson, <em>Jane</em></a></li>
    <li><a href="#person">Jetson, <em>Judy</em></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This page is loaded from the start of my application with code that looks like this (it's all in the same HTML page):

```
..snip..
<li class="arrow"><a href="#people">View all</a></li>
..snip..
```

What do I need to do to call my people.aspx service which returns JSON? I think I need to use `$.getJSON`, create a UL from the JSON, and then call something in jqtouch to transition to my people application page (div).

Answer (score 1):

I think you use [the goTo function](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/functions), e.g.

`jQT.goTo("#people")`

There's [a jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bwt9w/3/), but it doesn't test the jqTouch functionality.